# Proving the normality of t statistics gathered from independence testing from unknown distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test

We are given a distribution `P` with unknown characteristics.
Then, we repeatedly sample (without replacement) 2 samples from `P`.
We take these two samples, and we calculate the T-statistic using the independent t-test (without assuming equal variance). We repeat the process lots of times and gather all of the t values.

Can we be sure that all the t values, if we'll repeat the process enough times, will be normally distributed? If yes, what is the proof? If not can you give me a counter example?

Comment: Since we are sampling from the same distribution, on average they will have the same mean, so the t-test will return a t-value close to 0. The statistics will be normally distributed around 0. Proof is probably done using CLT.

Comment: @user2974951 When the underlying distribution has infinite variance, you won't get a normal distribution even when the sample sizes are large.  There are [many examples of this phenomenon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinite+variance+simulat*) shown in answers to (otherwise unrelated) questions on this site. Moreover, even in the case of finite variance the CLT doesn't apply unless you are contemplating taking *larger sample sizes* rather than repeating this process many times.